# Opening and writing file (csv) in python 3.7 on windows 10 randomly slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, csv, file

I have a loop that executes repeated. The loop showed to be sometimes very slow (35-60 seconds, instead of the expected 15-16 seconds). Every execution of the loop collects some data from a serial device. I introduced some logging to find the culprit and boiled it down to this:

```
        logging.info(f'Start Data collection after: {time.time() - starttime}s')
        for index, data in enumerate(return_data):
            file_data = f'{repetition}, ' \
                        f'{datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y.%m.%d")}, ' \
                        f'{datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")}, ' \
                        f'{return_data[index]["mid"]["drive_frequency"]}, ' \
                        f'{return_data[index]["mid"]["voltage"]}, ' \
                        f'{return_data[index]["mid"]["drive_current"]}, ' \
                        f'{return_data[index]["mid"]["analog_2_pressure"]}, ' \
                        f'{return_data[index]["end"]["analog_2_pressure"]}, ' \
                        f'{return_data2[index]["analog_2_pressure"]}, ' \
                        f'{return_data3[index]["mid"]["drive_frequency"]}, ' \
                        f'{return_data3[index]["mid"]["voltage"]}, ' \
                        f'{return_data3[index]["mid"]["drive_current"]}, ' \
                        f'{return_data3[index]["mid"]["analog_2_pressure"]}, ' \
                        f'{return_data3[index]["end"]["analog_2_pressure"]}' \
                        f'\n'
            try:
                with open(filepath[index], 'a') as f:
                    f.write(''.join(file_data))
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'File Error: {e}')
                with open(filename[index], 'a') as f:
                    f.write(''.join(file_data))
        logging.info(f'finished Data collection after: {time.time() - starttime}s')
```

The time between "Start Data Collection" and "Stop Data Collection" is usually arround 300 ms, but sometimes more than 30 s. The except block is not called, this usually only happens when the network path ("filepath") is not reachable to save the files locally.

The file operation is executed every 15 seconds (e.g. each loop).

Any idea what could take such a long time in this piece of code?

Comment: what does return data look like?

Comment: return_data is a list of dicts:

    dict = {'voltage': voltage, 'drive_current': drive_current, 'drive_power': 
    drive_power, 'drive_frequency': drive_frequency, 'analog_1_dial': analog_1_dial, 'analog_2_pressure': analog_2_pressure, 'analog_3_ai': analog_3_ai}

Comment: There are lots of questions marks popping up here. First one is why you write your own CSV formatting code instead of using the included one. Another obvious way to improve this is to not open and close files in a loop, only to write a single line. Keep the files open instead. Also, you could reap some benefits from doing this asynchronously. In order to find out what causes the delay, you could add further log entries, but keep in mind that those cause IO, too!

Comment: I did replace my formatting with the native csv package. And i added more logging. As thought, the open+writing take the time. I suppose its in the end a network issue and not a python one. But i am concluding more tests as i am writing.

Answer (score 0):

I see when you write the file you do `''.join(file_data)` which is not needed since your `file_data` variable is already a string (made by f-string). This function is going to create a new string concatenating each character (since you don't have a list of strings, your string will be considered a list of characters) which could increase the time for writing. Replace it by `f.write(file_data)`.

Comment: Thank you, i replaced the whole part with the native csv package. STill got the same issues, but think they are coming from the network, or a networked process that scans the files from time to time (cirus scan, backup, etc...).

Comment: Hi @ChrisP I would recommend you then to write the file locally and upload it every time you finish with writing the file instead. That probably will increase a bit the performance.

Comment: Thank you, thats what i am planning. I'll run a second script every 1000 cycles or so to copy the files...